# Reference returning blank value

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm writing a linked list, and using my `main` function to test it. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class LinkedList {
  int value;
  LinkedList* next;

  public:

    LinkedList(int valueIn, LinkedList* nextIn) {
      value = valueIn;
      next = nextIn;
    }
    LinkedList(int valueIn) {
      value = valueIn;
    }

    int getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    void addNode(LinkedList* node) {
      next = node;
    }

    LinkedList& getNext() {
      return *next;
    }
};

int main() {
  cout << "starting..." << std::endl;
  LinkedList list1(1);
  LinkedList list2(2, &list1);
  cout << list1.getValue() << " --> " << list1.getNext().getValue() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be `1 --> 2`, but I get `1 -->`. As far as I understand, `getNext()` should return a reference to another list (`list2` in this case), but something seems to be going wrong. My debugging efforts show me that `list2` does have the correct `value` 2 when it's initialized, but when it's referenced for the final output, it doesn't seem to have anything for `value`. I can't for the life of me figure out why this is. Could someone help me to understand?

Comment: Terminology: What you are calling a linked list is generally called a node or a link. A linked list class would manage a list of linked nodes.

Comment: Tactical note: `LinkedList(int valueIn)` should not leave `next` dangling. You should default to terminating the list to prevent possible errors. You could possibly remove the function and replace it with a slightly different `LinkedList(int valueIn, LinkedList* nextIn)` -> `LinkedList(int valueIn, LinkedList* nextIn = nullptr)`. If you do not specify a value for `nextIn`, the compiler will insert a `nullptr`, a common terminator from linked lists.

Comment: Thanks for the tips user4581301. I think the `LinkedList` as a class representing both a node and a whole list works, but it would probably be easier to understand if I made `LinkedList` and `node` two separate classes. I also didn't know about these dangerous dangling errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are insertin list1(which is actually a node) to the end of list2, not the other way around, yet you call `getNext()` on `list1`. You should change the code in main to the below:

```cpp
int main() {
  std::cout << "starting..." << std::endl;
  LinkedList list1(1);
  LinkedList list2(2, &list1);
  std::cout << list2.getValue() << " --> " << list2.getNext().getValue() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Please note that there are a couple of other things which would be better to change:

1. Create a list class and a Node class woud make things clearer
2. Initializing the pointer to be `NULL`(or `nullptr` from C++11) in the `LinkedList(int valueIn)` constructor
3. Return the pointer to the node in `getNext()` rather than copy the node

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting a blank value. Actually your program is crashing when you are trying to call `list1.getNext().getValue()` as `getNext()` is returning reference to a NULL.

You are doing the opposite of what you want to do.
Your `list2` is pointing to `list1` and `list1` is pointing to `NULL`.

You should change your code with this:

```
LinkedList list2(2);
LinkedList list1(1, &list2);
cout << list1.getValue() << " --> " << list1.getNext().getValue() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks -- I guess this was a pretty simple logic error. I thought it had something to do with a misunderstanding of pointers and references on my part, as they're a new concept to me. Thanks a ton for the answer.